# Clarification of the rleationship between two concepts

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, mathematical-modeling

In my studies I had contact with two concepts. The first is [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression). The second concept could be called reconstruction of a function, which also should be treated in school. For the reconstruction of a function you have mostly a set of points $S:=\left\{(x_1|y_1),...,(x_n|y_n)\right\}$ ($x_i \wedge y_i \in \mathbb{R}$) which are believed to be part of the graph of a function $f$. In my case a ploynomial function $f$. With the approach of solving the system

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x_1) &=& y_{1} \\
f(x_2)&=& y_{2} \\
& & & \vdots & \\
f(x_n) &=& y_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$

one might get the needed coefficients of the polynomial function.

Now my question is the following one:

Is the reconstruction of a function something like a special case of polynomial regression?

Comment: Use $n$ points to approximate the function in polynormal form?

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean by "polynormal"? In the case of the second concept you get a polynomial function whose graph contains all the n points, if the system has a solution. If the system has no solution the regression delivers at least a polynomial function whose graph does not contain all of the n points but has minimal square deviation in relation to the n points. My question is then in other words: Does the regression give me the same function as the second concept does, if the system has solution?

Comment: second concept gives a only solution of $n-1$ degree polynomial when given  $n$ different points for both $x_i$ and $y_i$ , but the regression can be applied in the case when $x_i$ may have same but $y_i$ different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution of interpolation (your second concept) and the solution of regression are different.
*Interpolation* and *Regression* are two different *curve fitting* method

**Concept**

1. Curve Fitting

   - Often have data, $y$, that is a function of some independent variable, $x$, but the
     underlying relationship is unknown

     - Know $y$’s and $x$’s (perhaps only approximately), but don’t know $f(x)$
   - Determine a function (i.e., a curve) that “best” describes relationship between $x$ and $y$

     - An approximation to (the unknown) $f(x)$
     - This is **Curve Fitting**
2. Regression vs. Interpolation

   We usually have two categories of curve fitting:

   - **Least‐squares regression**

     - Noisy data – uncertainty in $y$ value for a given $x$ value
     - Want “good” agreement between $f(x)$ and data points

       - Curve (i.e.$f(x)$) may not pass through any data points
   - **Polynomial interpolation**

     - Data points are known exactly – noiseless data
     - Resulting curve passes through all data points
       [image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that clarified the relation of both concepts for me.